# Vue.js vee-validate at least one checkbox needs be be unchecked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm allowing the user to dynamically add checkboxes to a form.  The user has the option to check or not.  What's the easiest way to check that at least one box needs to stay unchecked using vee-validate?

```
<div class="checkbox col-xs-12 form-group" 
    :class="{'has-error': errors.has('check[' + index + '][check_exclude]')}">
  <div class="checkbox"">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
           v-model="item.check_exclude" 
           v-validate data-vv-rules="max_value:0" 
           data-vv-as="Check Exclude" 
           name="check_exclude" 
           :name="'check[' + index + '][check_exclude]'" 
           value="1">
    </label>
    <span 
      v-cloak 
      v-show="errors.has('check[' + index + '][check_exclude]')" class="help-block">
    {{ errors.first('check[' + index + '][check_exclude]') }}
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your custom validator will enumerate all checkboxes and will do a logical AND of each `checkbox.checked` property - the result will be TRUE if **all** checkboxes are checked and FALSE if at least **one** checkbox is not checked. If you instead want to validate that ONLY 1 checkbox is not checked - then you need to do a SUM of all `checkbox.checked` (treating TRUE as 1, FALSE as 0) and compare this number to the count of checkboxes - if SUM + 1 == COUNT then exactly 1 checkbox is not checked.

Comment: @IVOGELOV perfect, thank you!  I wrote a function how you mentioned and it's working perfectly.  How do I evoke the validation error when sum == count?

Comment: I know this is long gone, but could you post the function you wrote? (as an answer)